# Maintain aspect ratio of resized images same as the original image ratio

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.3, intervention

I want to resize my through Intervention\Image in Laravel 5.3.
With the following code:

```
        $resized = Image::make($image)->resize(640, null, function ($constraint) {
                $constraint->aspectRatio(); })->stream();
        $resized_thumb = Image::make($image)->resize(320, 213)->stream();
```

I get images like this:
http://clasifire.com/listing?category=1 ( If you click the first image to go to its details you will find that its height is actually more)

But with this images lose the aspect ratio.
What I want is, for example, consider this list on craigslist: https://sfbay.craigslist.org/d/antiques/search/ata, (scroll down 3-4 lines)

So I do not want images to be stretched, instead they should maintain aspect ratio, leaving blank space along width/height if required.

Answer (score 0):

You should add another constraint:

```
$constraint->upsize();
```

after

```
$constraint->aspectRatio();
```

to prevent image from being scaled up if it's too small.

Comment: @RameshPareek Why not just try it and see?

Comment: Thanks. I will let you know shortly.

Comment: Okay. tested it, NOT working. May be my this line is creating the problem `  $resized_thumb = Image::make($image)->resize(320, 213)->stream();`, Because I am specifying dimensions. How do I only specify the width and let it decide the height?

Answer (score 0):

You may consider using a package like Glide to generate images on the fly (crop, size, effects, watermark, caching etc.) and keep the original image as is.
http://glide.thephpleague.com/

Comment: My question is about Intervention. Anyhow Thanks for suggesting a new library.

Comment: Glide uses Intervention too. It is based on it.

Comment: great!, I feel enlightened

Answer (score 0):

You should not specify with and height together! Only use one dimension and one of `widen()`  OR `heighten()` functions :

**By Height:**

```
$resized_thumb = Image::make($image)->heighten(320)->stream();
```

**By Width:**

```
$resized_thumb = Image::make($image)->widen(213)->stream();
```